# Magento 1.7: Remove pagination from top and keep pagination at bottom

Tags: pagination, magento-1.7, magento

I am using magento 1.7. In my home page each category has pagination and the pagination appears in both top and bottom of the each category. I want to remove pagination from top and keep pagination in bottom.

For including pagination, I used the following code,

CMS > Pages > Design > Layout Update XML

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="catalog/product_list" name="home" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>137</category_id></action>
    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
      <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
    </block>
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name><count>5</count></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello for pagination use gettoolbarhtml() check following file

**`/app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`**

comment below line

> // echo $this->getToolbarHtml()

Comment: Thank you..it worked..but path is app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product

Comment: Is it possible to use ajax for pagination?

Comment: getToolbarHtml() doesn't get only the pagination

Comment: @ErmaIsabel It is not a good idea to edit files from base/default directory. These are like Magento's code/core files. If you wish to have a more maintainable and clean code, you should extend and override Magento's files instead of changing them. Also, having the changes made in separate files, makes it easy to upgrade to a newer version of Magento without loosing any of your customizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal with something like this:

```
<reference name="your_parent_block_name">
    <remove name="block_name_you_want_to_remove"/>
</reference>
```